# multiple columns check in case when clause which has same values

Tags: sql, case, case-when

I am looking for some easy way for writing the following code in sql.

```
case
when (a_col in(1,2,3) or b_col in (1,2,3) or c_col in (1,2,3)) then "p"
when (d_col in (4,5) or e_col in (4,5)) then "q"
else null
end as new_Column
```

Is it possible to write something like

```
case
when (a_col  or b_col  or c_col) in (1,2,3) then "p"
when (d_col or e_col) in (4,5) then "q"
else null
end as new_Column
```

Comment: No, that is not possible.

Comment: Thanks for replying